# Une traduction pour « flawed proof »

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

En anglais, il y a une tournure qui veut dire qu’une preuve mathématique comprend des carences : on dit qu’une preuve contient des « fuites » (*The proof is flawed*). On l’emploie plutôt si la preuve est vraie à quelques petits arguments douteux près que quand la « preuve » est un fouillis de propos alambiqués. Il s’agit donc souvent d’un enchaînement de raisonnements qui devient une preuve véridique dès qu’on a rendu rigoureux les maillons faibles et louches.

En néerlandais, une traduction mot à mot est bien comprise bien qu’elle soit assez peu utilisée. J’aimerais être mis au courant s’il y a une tournure proche en français. Si c’est vrai, je veux savoir si cette tournure survient dans le langage habituel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

S'il y a réellement une erreur, *une démonstration [erronée](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/erron%C3%A9)*, [*inexacte*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/inexact), ou *une preuve [fausse](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faux)*. Familièrement « *Il y a un truc qui marche pas* ».

S'il n'y a que des doutes, comme tu le décris plus loin, *une démonstration douteuse*, [*bancale*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bancal) ou dans un registre imagé [*fumeuse*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fumeux). En langage très familier, j'imagine aussi facilement quelqu'un dire « *Elle est pourrie/moisie ta preuve* ».

Comment: +1 pour "démonstration bancale" qui traduit exactement la bonne idée. Cette possibilité m'avait échappé.

Comment: Le _fumeuse_ me semble beaucoup plus proche du "this is not even wrong" de Pauli que d'un manque de rigueur à certaines places.  On peut aussi utiliser _viciée_ qui complète facilement par une description de la faiblesse.

Answer (score 8):

On parle d'une **démonstration** (plutôt que preuve) contenant une ou plusieurs **failles**.

Cette tournure n'est pas spécifique aux mathématiques.

Note:

*Flaw* ne signifie pas fuite en anglais qui se traduit par *leak*, peut-être as-tu confondu avec *flow* ou *fled*.
Une traduction habituelle de *flaw* est « défaut ».

Comment: Merci pour me mettre au courant que j’ai mal compris le mot « flawed ». Je doute un peu de ce que je dois entreprendre maintenant. Dois-je enlever cette traduction fausse ? Ce n’est pas sage de répandre des énoncés fausses ici, quelque soit le sujet. 
D’autre part, un façonnage peut légèrement nuire l’à-propos dans l’ensemble des réponses et la question. Qu’en pensez-vous ?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Vu que la traduction la plus naturelle de *flaw* est *faille* ou *défaut* (suivant le domaine), la question n'aurait plus vraiment d'objet si on remplaçait *flaw* par sa traduction naturelle.

Comment: @Gilles: je crois que l'idée c'était justement d'enlever *flaw* complètement de la question, et de ne parler que de doutes.

Answer (score 3):

Je crois que seule une périphrase peut traduire "flawed", par exemple "cette preuve contient des erreurs".

Suivant le contexte, ces expressions peuvent être utilisées :

"Preuve inexacte" : moins fort que "fausse preuve", donc peut sous-entendre que la preuve a l'espoir d'être corrigée.

"Preuve incomplète" : pour insister sur l'absence d'un étape (plutôt qu'une faute).

Answer (score 3):

***"flawed proof"***

1- Si le contexte concerne la méthodologie on peut utiliser "raisonnement défaillant".
2- Si ça concerne la preuve elle même: "Preuve défaillante" ou "preuve insuffisante".
Tout dépend du contexte: Dans le deuxième cas (ie: la remarque concerne plutôt la preuve) la traduction devrait aller dans le sens à montrer qu'elle (la preuve) ne remplit pas sa fonction d’où le terme "insuffisante".

Je tendrais quand-même à utiliser le premier choix. A mon humble avis...