# Usage de la préposition en dans un énoncé mathématique

Tags: traduction, anglais, syntaxe, en

Je voudrais traduire l'énoncé :

[image]

Voici ma tentative :

[image]

Faut-il inclure *en* dans **on peut en conclure** (deux dernières lignes de la démonstration) ?

En outre, faut-il utiliser le participe présent (multipliant, soustrayant, etc.), le gérondif (en multipliant, en soustrayant, etc.), la 2e personne de l'impératif (multipliez, soustrayez, etc.), ou bien l'infinitif (multiplier, soustraire, etc.)?

NB Voici l'original (anglais) tiré du livre : A Math Primer for Engineers

[image]

Comment: C'est soit "La preuve que 1=0", soit "Une démonstration que 1=0". Voir aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9772/1109

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Fallacious proof et preuve (ou démonstration) fallacieuse ? N'est-ce pas ? Peut-être il me faut poser une question nouvelle:-)!

Comment: "Preuve" correspond plus souvent à *evidence*, *proof* correspond plus souvent à "démonstration" et *demonstration* correspond parfois à "manifestation"...

Comment: Pour les étapes, je mettrais "on multiplie", "on soustrait", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Preuve* n'est pas faux, mais on dit plutôt **démonstration** en mathématiques, et plus généralement en sciences. C'est plus une question d'usage que de sens. La nuance est subtile. Une expérience de physique peut *démontrer expérimentalement* une théorie, mais on dit alors que la théorie *a une preuve expérimentale*.

Je ne dirais pas une « [démonstration fallacieuse](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22d%C3%A9monstration+fallacieuse%22) » même si d'autres se le permettent. Une démonstration est par définition correcte, sinon ce ne serait pas une démonstration. Ici le bon terme est ***[raisonnement fallacieux](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22raisonnement+fallacieux%22)*** : un raisonnement est une succession d'idées et de déductions qui n'est pas forcément correcte à priori.

Pour les étapes, le participe présent (ce n'est pas un participe passé !) convient, avec la préposition *en* : « en multipliant », etc. (Je ne suis pas sûr que le terme *gérondif* soit encore enseigné en France de nos jours pour « en + participe présent », je l'associe à l'apprentissage de la grammaire latine.) Mais je trouve que la présentation est un peu bizarre, il semble manquer des verbes. J'écrirais plutôt

> En multipliant les deux côtés par *x*, on obtient …

Cela fait partie du style qui consiste à écrire impersonnellement, en utilisant le pronom *on*. Ce style évite tout pronom personnel et utilise des formules telles que « d'après le théorème machin, on a … » ou « le théorème machin permet de conclure que … ». Une autre manière de rédiger dans ce style, peut-être plus fréquente, est d'utiliser la préposition *par*.

> Par multiplication des deux côtés par *x*, on obtient …

Les démonstrations mathématique sont souvent rédigées à la première personne du pluriel, à l'impératif présent lorsqu'il s'agit d'effectuer une opération et à l'indicatif présent lorsqu'il s'agit d'une constatation. « Nous » inclut l'auteur du texte et le lecteur.

> Multiplions les deux côtés par *x* : …. Nous en concluons que *x* = 0.

Ici on peut aussi utiliser l'impératif avec le vous de politesse (« multipliez » — avec le verbe au pluriel, mais d'éventuels adjectifs au singulier). Cela permet de distancier l'auteur d'un raisonnement faux : l'auteur n'est pas en train de faire une démonstration mathématique, mais enjoindre le lecteur à faire une expérience de raisonnement. L'infinitif est aussi possible pour décrire un algorithme.

« Il a été prouvé » peut à la rigueur passer, mais je trouve le passif « il a été supposé » vraiment trop lourd. Là il n'y a pas vraiment de choix, c'est la première personne du pluriel qui est la plus naturelle. De plus, en français, la [conjonction *or*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/or#Conjonction_de_coordination) s'impose ici pour rappeler une hypothèse passée. Elle est très courante dans les raisonnements (mathématiques et autres).

> Nous avons prouvé que *x* = 0. Or nous avions initialement supposé que *x* = 1. Nous en concluons que 1 = 0.

(On peut aussi faire une seule phrase avec des virgules.)

Comment: Le terme gérondif est utilisé en grammaire française, habituel en FLE pour le différencier du participe présent, Grevisse y consacre plusieurs pages (sens, emploi, gérondif et p.présent), articles de recherche sur le sujet,  et le terme semble revenir dans les termes grammaticaux utilisés [dans le secondaire](https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/38/francais-4e/chapitre/384/fiches-de-conjugaison-orthographe/page/692848/les-formes-en-ant-participe-gerondif-et-adjectif-verbal/lecon).

Comment: *Une démonstration est par définition correcte, sinon ce ne serait pas une démonstration.* Une démonstration n'est que la présentation d'un raisonnement mais ce raisonnement n'est pas nécessairement correct. Un adjectif peut atténuer ou contredire la justesse d'une démonstration. Une démonstration peut donc être controversée, bancale, irrecevable, erronée, fausse....Je suis cependant d'accord sur le fait que *raisonnement fallacieux* est meilleur que *démonstration fallacieuse*.

Answer (score -1):

Bon alors, tu l'as écrit toi-même au début... ***une preuve fallacieuse***...

Sachant de plus que ton STEP 1 est une hérésie mathématique maximum...

Je ne vois pas bien ce que tu te compliques la vie à chercher quelque rigueur langagière...

Dans la vraie vie (celle des maths plus rigoureuses) je dirais que dans le cas où comme ici :

Proposition A **.** Proposition B **,** *On peut **en** conclure* => on concluera **DE B!** C'est B qui permet de conclure.

Proposition A **.** Proposition B **,** *On peut conclure* => on concluera **DE A ET DE B!** C'est A ET B qui permettent de conclure.

Qui serait alors équivalent à :

*Proposition A ET proposition B. On peut en conclure.*

Tu vises donc ici un sujet de pure **syntaxe**.

Dans ton exemple foireux ici (Car en fait A n'a rien prouvé du tout), je choisirais donc : ***On peut conclure.***

Pour ce qui est du choix du mode, je dirais q**u'il faut être cohérent avec l'entame.**
Tu a choisis la première personne du pluriel ***supposons*** alors **sois conséquent**... continue à la première personne du pluriel : Multiplions, soustrayons...

Après et encore, tout n'étant que pour la blague... tu peux bien changer à chaque ligne... pour... ce qui te chante...

Comment: Merci ! À propos, la preuve est tiré par l'ouvrage anglais A Math Primer for Engineers (CW Cryer). L'auteur donne comme référence : Nitsa
Movshovitz-Hadar, John Webb One Equals Zero and Other Mathematical Surprises:
Paradoxes, Fallacies, and Mind Bogglers. Voir la version actualisée de la question. Je ne comprends pas ladite "hérésie" :-)!

Comment: @Dimitris En termes d'hérésie maths, tu préfères peut-être STEP3 -> STEP4 que tu ne peux écrire sans préciser X<>1. (Sinon tu divises par 0)

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, c'est bien le principe : c'est prévu pour être fallacieux

Comment: @Evpok : Oui, j'avais bien compris mais je m'amusais plus aux dépends de Dimitris que l'ont sait physicien. Car... usuellement... c'est à eux que la division par 0 fait tourner de l'oeil... pas aux matheux. On a side note, je préférais e^i2pi = e^i4pi qui "prouve" que soit 2 = 4 soit... i=0 ;-)

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord pour « on peut (en) conclure ». L'antécédent de la préposition *en* n'est pas clairement délimité, il peut s'agir de B seul ou de A et B. « On peut en conclure » est donc correct. Je trouve « on peut conclure » un peu bizarre : il laisse penser qu'il y a un saut dans la démonstration, on est arrivé à une étape, ensuite on conclut mais on ne sait pas comment.

Answer (score -6):

Votre présentation de preuve est acceptable mis à part que la dernière phrase est à modifier ; comme vous le suspectez, « en » est en trop. De plus le passif n'est ni usuel en français ni dans le français des mathématiques. « Côté » n'est pas utilisé ou très peu ; on parles des membres d'une équation couramment cependant. « De sortes que » ne peut pas commencer une phrase.

**Preuve erronée que 1 = 0**

*Supposons que x = 1*. **ou**  *On suppose que x = 1*. **ou** *Soit x = 1*. (*Le point peut être remplacé par un point virgule.*)

(ÉTAPE 1)     en multipliant les deux membres par x                      *x² = x* ;
(ÉTAPE 2)     en soustrayant 1 des deux membres                     *x²-1 = x-1* ;
(ÉTAPE 3)      en factorisant le membre de gauche           *(x-1)(x+1) = x-1* ;
(ÉTAPE 4)      en divisant les deux membres par *x-1* ;                *x+1 = 1*  ;
(ÉTAPE 5)      soustrayant *1* des deux membres                             *x = 0*  ;

nous avons donc prouvé que *x = 0*. Comme on a supposé initialement que *x = 0* on peut conclure que *1 = 0*.

---

Cette présentation serait  plus usuelle si certaines autres modifications étaient faites : suppression des gérondif, des points virgules (pas de points virgule dans les développements de nos jours), et remplacement de « stage » par « eq. ». Optionnellement, la conclusion peut être considérée comme le dernier stage du développement. Donc, tenant compte de tout cela la présentation pourrait être comme suit. Ne pas oublier que ce n'est qu'une possibilité à peu près dans les normes et que d'autres sont aussi acceptables ; par exemple, les explications peuvent être placées après les équations (mais il me semble que vous devriez déjà  avoir une bonne idée cela).

*Supposons que x = 1*. **ou**  *On suppose que x = 1*. **ou** *Soit x = 1*.

(eq. 1)      multiplication des deux membres par x                   *x² = x*
(eq. 2)      soustraction de 1 des deux membres                   *x²-1 = x-1*
(eq. 3)      factorisation du membre de gauche            *(x-1)(x+1) = x-1*
(eq. 4)      division  des deux membres par *x-1*                      *x+1 = 1*
(eq. 5)      soustraction de *1* des deux membres                       *x = 0*
(eq. 6)      substitution de la valeur de *x*                                    *1 = 0*

On obtient ainsi une preuve de *1 = 0*.

PLUS BREF

*Supposons que x = 1*; **ou**  *On suppose que x = 1*; **ou** *Soit x = 1*;

(eq. 1)      multiplication par x                   *x² = x*
(eq. 2)      soustraction de 1                  *x²-1 = x-1*
(eq. 3)      factorisation                 *(x-1)(x+1) = x-1*
(eq. 4)      division  par *x-1*                      *x+1 = 1*
(eq. 5)      soustraction de *1*                       *x = 0*
(eq. 6)      substitution de 1 pour *x*             *1 = 0*

On obtient ainsi une preuve de *1 = 0*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98934/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-usage-de-la-preposition-en-dans-un-enonce-mathematiq).