# Fallacieux et fallacious

Tags: anglais, usage, adjectifs, faux-amis

Quand le mot *fallacious* est-il traduit par fallacieux ?

Existe-il des exemples où les deux adjectifs sont des faux amis ?

Voici un exemple d'utilisation :

> Most famous open problems in mathematics have attracted fallacious proofs or disproofs,
>   usually, but not always, due to amateurs. A trivial example of a **fallacious proof** is given
>   below. The original source is not known to the author but a modern source is Nitsa
>   Movshovitz-Hadar, John Webb One Equals Zero and Other Mathematical Surprises:
>   Paradoxes, Fallacies, and Mind Bogglers [MHW98].
>   (A Math Primer for Engineers)

Voir aussi la question : [Usage de la préposition en dans un énoncé mathématique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39606/usage-de-la-pr%c3%a9position-en-dans-un-%c3%a9nonc%c3%a9-math%c3%a9matique)

Comment: @Laure À propos la question ici vient de la discussion entre LPH et Evpok. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98934/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-usage-de-la-preposition-en-dans-un-enonce-mathematiq Sans faute de ma part il n'y pas un consensus qui me laisse un peu perplexe. Je vais modifier la question.

Comment: Tu peux faire confiance à Evpok. [Fallacious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/fallacious) ; [fallacieux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fallacieux)

Comment: Je ne répondrai à la question car je sais qu'il y a ici des personnes ayant fait des études scientifiques à en très haut niveau, mais j'ai facilement trouvé cette phrase sur un site de [formation mathématiques post bac](http://www.masterclassprepa.com/comment-reussir-en-mathematiques.html) :  « la rigueur mathématique tant sur le fond (être capable de parvenir au résultat final sans jamais utiliser de raisonnement fallacieux, sauter d’étape intermédiaire ou oublier de cas particulier) que dans la forme (utilisation d’une écriture mathématique irréprochable) ...». et d'autres.

Comment: Les faux-amis (partiels) dans l'expression *fallacious proof*, ce sont *proof* et preuve. *Fallacious* et fallacieux ont le même sens dans cette phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lors de mes études scientifiques en France je n'ai jamais entendu 'fallacieux', alors qu'au cours de mes études et emplois scientifiques dans des pays anglophones... je n'ai jamais entendu 'fallacious'. Je n'ai vu ce dernier que dans des textes en anglais de philosophie analytique.

Les physiciens, ingénieurs et mathématiciens appliqués ne l'employaient pas : ils disaient 'faux', 'illogique', 'incohérent', etc. Le mot anglais est donc usité dans des champs très spécifiques. Mais je ne sais pas si les gens que je côtoyais l'auraient compris sans l'utiliser eux-mêmes.

'Fallacious' a (ou du moins peut avoir) un sens neutre et objectif : un argument qui n'est pas valide, pas logique, mais sans malhonnêteté. Je n'ai jamais vu ce sens pour 'fallacieux', qui signifie 'de mauvaise foi'.

Comment: Pure mathematicians don't seem to use it either; looking at online discussions of Kempe's famous fallacious proof of the four-color theorem ([*théorème de quatre couleurs*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_quatre_couleurs)), the only adjectives commonly used are *faux* and *erroné.*

Answer (score 0):

Un argumentaire est fallacieux lorsqu'il est entaché d'erreurs telles qu'elles l'invalident.

Let me go on in English: a reasoning is fallacious nonetheless because there is a logic mistake in it, but also there is a deceitful component, some type of a bad intention and dishonesty. The latter aspect is not present in the French word "fallacieux", although the mistakes referred to are serious.

Answer (score -1):

D'après le Dictionnaire universel des synonymes de la langue française (1816), par Gabriel Girard, il ne fait aucun doute, le mot « fallacieux » avait essentiellement une signification associé avec la mauvaise foi, la malhonnêteté, en particulier d'un point de vue religieux. Donc lorsque les emplois à traduire proviennent de texte assez anciens « fallacious » est traduisible par « fallacieux ».

[image]

Dans ce livre plus récent, *La manipulation, nouvelle édition 2013: Identifier les …* , il n'est question que d'arguments qui visent à manipuler les gens et l'adjectif central dans la description de cet aspect des relations humaines est encore « fallacieux » ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4UFlAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=%22fallacieux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwuruP5-LkAhUHfBoKHZVsDpc4ChDoAQhMMAU#v=onepage&q=%22fallacieux%22&f=false)).

L'exemple suivant encore selon un usage récent montre que l'argument fallacieux émane d'un biais associé avec la personne qui émet l'argument, d'une malhonnêteté plus ou moins consciente ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Zya4wpdXNKEC&pg=PA271&dq=%22fallacieux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivg_3o7uLkAhXEzYUKHf2BALA4HhDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22fallacieux%22&f=false)).

Voici un autre cas d'usage récent qui ne laisse aucun doute ; ce mot connote essentiellement la malhonnêteté ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JjeoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&dq=%22fallacieux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivg_3o7uLkAhXEzYUKHf2BALA4HhDoAQguMAE#v=onepage&q=%22fallacieux%22&f=false)).

[image]

« Ce qui est fait pour induire en erreur est fallacieux » trouve-t-on encore dans ce [dictionnaire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=umUTAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22fallacieux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizwsWi8eLkAhWo34UKHdQtCS44MhDoAQg1MAI#v=onepage&q=%22fallacieux%22&f=false) comme définition ; il est clair que ce qui est « fait » l'est par l'esprit de l'homme.

L'extrait suivant montre qu'en français cet adjectif est toujours utilisé selon son acception originelle, alors qu'en anglais il n'est plus employé spécifiquement comme tel mais dans le sens dérivé de ce qui trompe (deceptive, misleading). Le sens « deceitful » est obsolète en anglais.

[image]

Néanmoins, « fallacieux » est quand même utilisé en logique philosophique  pour décrire les arguments dits fallacieux. Il n'est donc plus question de malhonnêteté ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=L-1tzRpNj34C&pg=PT258&dq=%22fallacieux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizwsWi8eLkAhWo34UKHdQtCS44MhDoAQhVMAc#v=onepage&q=%22fallacieux%22&f=false)).

« Fallacious » peut être traduit à la rigueur par « fallacieux » lorsque il s'agit de simple erreur et on trouve cet usage  dans le domaine de la logique en général en particulier associé au mot « argument » (argument fallacieux, sophisme), bien que dans la logique mathématique en France on n'utilise pas ces termes ; où les Anglo-Saxons utilise « fallacy », « sophism » et « fallacious » en France on utilise « sophism » et « argument non valide ».

Selon [l'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophisme) dans son article sur les sophisme et la logique philosophique, « un sophisme est une argumentation à la logique fallacieuse ». Cependant, cette acception ne convient pas à la logique mathématique ; on n'utilise pas « fallacieux » dans les livres de logique mathématique ; on parle tout simplement d'argument faux ou de sophisme. On n'utilise pas le terme non plus dans le texte mathématique, comme la logique dans le texte mathématique est la logique mathématique, pas la logique philosophique, laquelle est une extension de la première. On ne devrait donc pas traduire « fallacious » par « fallacieux » trop légèrement dans ces deux domaines.